# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleabl

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm having problems with Google Maps v2 in Android. I had a code that it was working but after  updating Eclipse and changed something it isn't working. I'm having the error in this line:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);
```

I'm using a SupportMapFragment inside an ActionBarActivity. My XML is the next one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextLocation"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:hint="@string/search"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:padding="5dp" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonMap"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:text="@string/accept"
    android:textColor="@color/White" >
</Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

After reading some stackoverflow pages I think that there is a problem with Google Play Services. I have imported the library project and added the library to my project. 
[image: Google Play Services added to my project]

And my build path is as shown in next image:

[image]

I think I've done everything I've read over there but this isn't working.

And this line is returning 0, which is the value of Ok or Success:

```
  GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity())));

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EnterPageFragment fragment = new EnterPageFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
}
}
```

Comment: is both the library project and your android project in the same folder?. you need to import the library project into workspace

Comment: Can you post activity Code? And Yes try solution from above.

Comment: is those two library on libs folder too?

Comment: No, there aren't in the same folder... But I've tried this now and it wsn't working either.

Comment: Make sure your application and the google play services library are imported in the same folder. And also check that your libraries are not taking reference from the imported library as well as from the library which you have added in your project .

Comment: @JonZangitu from your second screenshot you can see that you have imported `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` and `googleplayservice.jar` are taking multiple references which is also cause of error.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I've only imported it once, I don't have .jar's in my libs folder. Why could be this happening? They're just added as library projects.

Comment: @JonZangitu do you have both the projects in the same folder?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes they are in the same folder, ../dev/android-project and ../dev/google-play-services_lib

Comment: @JonZangitu the error happens usually when you have not referenced the library project properly.

Comment: @JonZangitu make sure that in `Projects` tab there is not any library added as project if its added then remove that.

Comment: @Raghunandan and in that case the .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() would be correct? I know something is not correct with Google Play Services, but I don't know what to do. I've followed all instructions...

Comment: @JonZangitu you are checking for the availability of google play services on your device. Bu the error happens when you don't refer to the library proejct properly

Comment: It seemed everything was correct and it didn't work. I used a new eclipse and a new project, doing everything like before and now it works. Eclipse, android sdk or something was corrupted I think.